# UIImageView remove white area after rotation applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem with rotating UIImageView. As you look at the attached screenshot you will find that image is rotated but the frame of UIImageView has some unwanted empty area. The blue line around image is the frame of UIImageView.

How can I remove that empty area? And assign that much of frame which is require by image.

[image: This is screenshot]